# Closing of established database connection in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am new to drupal and I am trying to use drupal 6 for my web application. I have gone through the basic code flow of drupal and came to know that functions in bootstrap.inc is to be executed on every drupal request. The database connections are written in the same file, but closing the established database connections are not mentioned anywhere in the code.

So my doubt is, how to close these connections? does it create any errors if it is left open?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This is from the php documentation.

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See also freeing resources.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php